# Vue.extend and $mount() alternative for a Vue3 repository

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, web-component

I am implementing Micro-Frontend Architecture in my Vue2 repo, where I made various web components and injected them in the parent repo named admin_portal.

After upgrading this repository from Vue2 to Vue3, I am stuck in a method where I use **Vue.extend** and **$mount()**.

Attaching a method where I am facing this issue:

```js
renderService(node) {
  const query = Object.keys(this.$route.query).length ?
    this.$route.query :
    "";
  const attrsString = `:token="accessToken" ${
        query ? ':search-params="params"' : ""
      }`;
  const ServiceClass = Vue.extend({
    template: `<${this.service.tagname} ${attrsString}></${this.service.tagname}>`,
    props: ["service", "params"]
  });
  const instance = new ServiceClass({
    propsData: {
      service: this.service,
      params: JSON.stringify(query)
    },
    name: this.service.tagname,
    store: this.$store,
    computed: {
      accessToken() {
        return this.$store.state.auth.user.token;
      }
    }
  });
  instance.$mount();
  if (node) {
    this.$refs.serviceContainer.replaceChild(instance.$el, node);
  } else {
    this.$refs.serviceContainer.appendChild(instance.$el);
  }
  this.instance = instance.$el;
},
```

**Vue.extend** & **$mount()** are deprecated in Vue3.

[Attaching a documentation URL of Vue2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) where the above code is still working.
After my repo was upgraded from Vue2 to Vue3, I again want to implement the same kind of thing.

Comment: Seems like you need dynamic components - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components